# Django sort model objects by intersection count of a property with another QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with Django querying. I searched through web but still couldn't find a solution to it.

I have a model called Question:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tagged_questions')
    ...
```

And I need to write a method which is as below:

```
def get_recommended_questions(request):
    ...
    interested_tags = user.interested_tags.all()
    recommended_questions_list = ... // I need help here
```

I need to get a list of `Question` objects, which are sorted by the intersection count of their `tags` with `interested_tags`

For example:

```
interested_tags = [A, B, C]
```

And I have following questions in the database:

```
q1.tags = [A, B, C] // intersection count = 3
q2.tags = [D] // intersection count = 0
q3.tags = [A, B, D] // intersection count = 2
q4.tags = [A, D] // intersection count = 1
```

What I want to get is:

```
recommended_questions_list = [q1, q3, q4]
```

I want to know if there is a way to do this without using raw SQL.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's long query so I will go step by step

```
def get_recommended_questions(request):
    ...
    interested_tags = user.interested_tags.all()
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    recommended_questions_list = [(question, 
             len(set(interested_tags)&set(list(question.tags.all())))) 
             for question in questions]
    # the above list has tuples with question object and intersection count
```

Now you can sort however you want

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask 2 more questions? The first one is whether it can be done using complicated django queries; and the second one is whether this way has worse performance than django queries.

Comment: See intersection like query that you want can't be solely done by django. You have to manually loop through objects and then perform intersection. @desperado

Answer (score 2):

In this, first we require to get all the `questions` that has any of the tag in which user is interested.
Then we can sort it based on the total matched `tags` between user and question.

Sample code:

```
interested_tags_ids = user.interested_tags.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
questions = Question.objects.filter(tags__in=interested_tags_ids).prefetch_related('tags')
interested_tags_set = set(interested_tags_ids)

sort_func = lambda question: len(set(question.tags.all().values_list('id', flat=True)) & interested_tags_set)
recommended_questions_list = sorted(questions, key=sort_func, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Good solution. But just one small problem OP asked for objects and you are giving IDs. Objects can be retrieved by id also but seems like unnecessary overhead

Comment: `recommended_questions_list` has list of `Question` objects. I am fetching ids for `tags` only because in current context not using it anywhere else.

Comment: In my case this solution seems to be better because it filters only the relevant `questions` before loading them into memory. On top of that it struggles to reduce database usage to a minimum, using `values_list` and `prefetch_related`.